# Calculate Average Service Duration PowerBI - multiple IDs

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to calculate the average service time of a chatbot grouping by its source. The problem is I only have the date of the server to each message. Therefore, I need to take the max and min datetime of each contact and calculate the difference (2 mins for X and  20 mins for Y), and then obtain the global average duration (11 min for source A in this case since there are 2 unique contacts).

| Contact2__c | ServerDateTime__c | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 01/10/2022 13:20:00 | A |
| X | 01/10/2022 13:20:15 | A |
| X | 01/10/2022 13:22:00 | A |
| Y | 01/10/2022 14:00:00 | A |
| Y | 01/10/2022 14:05:00 | A |
| Y | 01/10/2022 14:20:00 | A |

Any idea on how to procceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did this a hideous way, but this is how I did it:

I created a calculated table using SUMMARIZE to return the earliest and latest Server times per Contact and Source, like this:

```
ContactSummary = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'ContactData',
    'ContactData'[Contact2__c],
    'ContactData'[Source],
    "StartTime", MIN('ContactData'[ServerDateTime__c]),
    "EndTime", MAX('ContactData'[ServerDateTime__c]),
    "Duration",DATEDIFF(
                  MIN('ContactData'[ServerDateTime__c]),
                  MAX('ContactData'[ServerDateTime__c]),
                  MINUTE)
)
```

SUMMARIZE basically lets me do a grouping by [Contact2__c] and [Source] so I get two values from that (20 and 2).

Then I created an Average Duration measure:

```
avg duration = AVERAGE('ContactSummary'[Duration])
```

Finally, I put Source and Avg Duration in a table, so I end up with {"A", 11.00} as my final result.  Sum of A = 22, count of rows = 2, so 22/2 = 11.

Maybe I overexplained it, but if I made a mistake someone should be able to point it out pretty easily. =)